# How to get all possible location based on given search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

I need to get all possible location from given string, I know its available in Google API, but I want in apple native API.
I have tried following 2 codes, but both are return only one location, but need all possible solution for given input.
It is available in iOS API ? Please help me to solve this.

Code 1 :

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
   [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       NSLOG(@"Count %d",placemarks.count);
       [self.tableView reloadData];
       });
   }];
```

Code 2 :

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = address;
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
       NSLOG(@"Count %d",response.mapItems.count);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

please check[image: map search] the image , i need all possible "placemarks" like attachment

Comment: What do you mean by all possible locations?  What defines a location; a latitude + longitude, or something like a business or landmark?

Comment: Code 1 doesn't work？

Comment: @trojanfoe I need like a map search. eg: if i type the "salem" i need to get all placemarks (salem). i have edited the my question with image please check that

Comment: @childrenOurFuture : it ll return only one plackmark